# VueJS: Why v-model does not work with a vuejs filter

Tags: vuejs2, javascript-objects

Why `v-model` does not work with a filter `getUppercase` in `<input v-model="filterText | getUppercase">`

**HTML**

```
<template>
  <div class="wrapper">
    Check if fruit exist: <input v-model="filterText | getUppercase">
    <ul v-for="fruit in filteredFruits">
      <li> {{ fruit }} </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</template>
```

**VueJS**

```
export default {
  name: "filterText",
  data() {
    return {
      msg: "Welcome to Your Vue.js App",
      filterText: "",
      fruits: ["Apple", "Banana", "Orange", "PineApple", 'Pina Colada']
    };
  },
  computed: {
    filteredFruits: function() {
      var vm = this;
      return vm.fruits.filter(function(item) {
        return item.match(vm.filterText)
      });
    }
  },
  filters: {
    getUppercase: function(obj) {
      return this.obj.toUpperCase();
    }
  }
};
```

Comment: Define "does not work".

Answer (score 1):

I can see what you are trying to do, however, because of the two way binding when using v-model, it will be better to just apply the `getUppercase` filter when displaying.

Your template would be something like this:

```
<template>
 <div class="wrapper">
   Check if fruit exist: <input v-model="filterText">
   <ul v-for="fruit in filteredFruits">
     <li> {{ fruit | getUppercase}} </li>
   </ul>
 </div>
</template>
```

But if you still wish to transform the `filterText` model value, you can use a directive. In that case, your VueJS code will be something like :

```
Vue.directive('getUppercase', {
  twoWay: true, // this transformation applies back to the filterText
  bind: function () {
    var self = this;
    self.handler = function () {
     self.set(self.el.value.toUpperCase());
    }
    self.el.addEventListener('input', self.handler);
  },
  unbind: function () {
   this.el.removeEventListener('input', this.handler);
  }
 });
```

Now use this directive in your template like :

```
<input v-model="filterText" v-get-uppercase="filterText">
```

It will do the same thing as `<input v-model="filterText | getUppercase">`

Answer (score -1):

> Two ways filters are replaced in vue.js please read the [docs](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/migration.html#Two-Way-Filters-replaced) for more information.It is good to know.

However,as i understood you want to implement a search in array.[See it in action here](https://jsfiddle.net/Roland1993/180bkaa6/), or take a look below

```
<div id="app">
  Check if fruit exist: <input v-model="filterText">
    <ul v-for="fruit in filteredFruits">
      <li> {{ fruit }} </li>
    </ul>
</div>

new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data: {
    filterText: "",
     fruits: ["Apple", "Banana", "Orange", "PineApple", 'Pina Colada']
  },
    computed: {
    filteredFruits() {
        return this.fruits.filter(item => item.toLowerCase().match(this.filterText.toLowerCase()))
    }
  }
})
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I know how filters are to be used, for e.g `<p>{{ sometext | getUppercase }}</p>` this will work since the text to the left of the pipe will be passed to the filter method (to the right)  but I am more interested in knowing why filters doesn't work in this statement `<input v-model="filterText | getUppercase">`.

Comment: I answered to your question.Because you are using filter in v-model and that is named two way filters.And two way filters are replaced.Please take a closer look to my answer.